# Last Row of GridView Edit Fails

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a requirement to add a Sub-Total and Total to a Gridview. After adding the Code for the Sub-Total and Total rows, on final data row of the grid the "Edit" button no longr fires it's event. The rest of the grid's edit events fire. I have several grids with varying "sub-sections"

What I have found out so far:

The number of Sub-Total rows is the same as the number of Rows that do not fire the Edit event. (IE If there are 2 Sub-Total Rows then the Last two Edit buttons no longer fire the event, Only cause a postback which removes the Sub-Total rows. If there are 3 then 3 edits do not work, Etc Etc))

Without the Sub-Total rows the Edit event works as expected.

Here is the Code I am using to build the grid and Sub-Total/Total rows:

Row_DataBound:

```
Protected Sub gvFTEMedProc_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvFTEMedProc.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "F_Med_Proced") <> "FTE Health Room Visit" Then
            If medicationCount <= 9 Then
                medicationCount += 1
                medicationProcedureType = "Medication"
            Else
                medicationCount += 1
                medicationProcedureType = "Procedures"
            End If
            Dim dblMedProcCount As Double = Convert.ToDouble(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "F_Med_Proced_Num"))
            dblMedProcTotal += dblMedProcCount
            grandTotalMedProc += dblMedProcCount
        End If
    End If
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).ColumnSpan = 2
        e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Total (minus Health Room Visits):"
        e.Row.Cells(1).ColumnSpan = 2
        e.Row.Cells(1).Text = grandTotalMedProc.ToString("n0")
        e.Row.Cells(0).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        e.Row.Cells(1).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        e.Row.Cells(2).Visible = False
        e.Row.Cells(3).Visible = False
        e.Row.Font.Bold = True
        medicationProcedureType = String.Empty
        medicationCount = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Row_Created:

```
Protected Sub gvFTEMedProc_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvFTEMedProc.RowCreated
    Dim IsSubTotalRowNeeded As Boolean = False

    If (medicationProcedureType <> String.Empty) AndAlso (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "F_Med_Proced") IsNot Nothing) Then
        If medicationCount = 9 Then 'DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "School_Type").ToString() Then
            IsSubTotalRowNeeded = True
        End If
    End If

    If (medicationProcedureType <> String.Empty) AndAlso (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "F_Med_Proced") Is Nothing) Then
        IsSubTotalRowNeeded = True
        intSubTotalIndex = 0
    End If
    If medicationProcedureType = "Procedures" Then
        Dim rowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex
    End If
    'The Issue is happening when I add this IF Statement.
    If IsSubTotalRowNeeded Then
        Dim gvtest As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)

        'Create a Row
        Dim SubTotalRow As New GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert)

        'Adding Total Cell
        Dim HeaderCell As New TableCell()
        HeaderCell.Text = medicationProcedureType + " Sub Total:"
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2
        HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right
        HeaderCell.CssClass = "SubTotalRowStyle"
        SubTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell)

        'Adding Medication Column
        HeaderCell = New TableCell()
        HeaderCell.Text = String.Format("{0:N0}", dblMedProcTotal)
        HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2
        HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        HeaderCell.CssClass = "SubTotalRowStyle"
        SubTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell)

        'Adding the Row at the RowIndex position in the Grid
        gvtest.Controls(0).Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + intSubTotalIndex, SubTotalRow)
        intSubTotalIndex += 1

        dblMedProcTotal = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

And the ASP:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFTEMedProc" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
        Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf_HCID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("FTE_MP_ID") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="F_Med_Proced" HeaderText="FTE Medication Procedure" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="F_Med_Proced_Num" HeaderText="FTE Medication Procedure Number"
                DataFormatString="{0:N0}" />
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Edit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30px" HeaderText="Delete" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I have seen odd behavior like this when dynamically adding rows to a datagrid. Are you opposed to trying a DataList or Repeater instead? http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/displaying-data-with-the-datalist-and-repeater-controls-vb

Comment: I have checked out that link and unfortunately it is not something we can do at this time. My options (per requirements) are to figure out why this strange behavior is happening and fix the last few edit buttons or completely re-write the 20+ pages to use in-line editing instead of populating a gridview.

Comment: Is there any code in the RowUpdating() function (vb)?  Also, just to be sure, your databinding call is in your page_load and inside of a "if not page.ispostback() then" block?

Comment: I do not have anything for RowUpdating. The above are the only two functions I have added Code to. I call the databinding function when I need it, The user must select an option from a drop down and once the selection is made The Change event for the drop down calls the binding to populate the grid.

Comment: While I would love to know why this worked... So after your response I changed the way my Page_Load worked. Instead of only calling the binding when a DropDown item was pre-selected. I now just call the Function for the change event of the drop down in the Page_Load function. This solved the issue, all the "Edit" buttons now work as expected, as well as, the Sub-Total and Total Lines never disappear. Thank You @TimG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to add the databinding into the Page_Load. (However, in my case, it was required for every page_load not only "if not page.ispostback()")

In my case I was only binding the data when a selection from the Drop Down menu was made. Therefore, when the page loaded on a postback it would not rebind the Edit columns of the grid (oddly enough only the last 1-3 rows of the grid would not bind, the first 10-12 rows would bind normally)

In my Change Event function, I handled if the selection was valid or not and called the databinding function if a valid selection was made. By adding the Change Event Function to the Page_Load the issue was resolved. The Edit buttons and grid now functions as expected on every page_load, postback or not.